# Is it possible to modify a single email account's maximum attachment size in cPanel?

Tags: email, attachment

In cPanel, how can I adjust the maximum attachment size for a users email account?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should look for "message_size_limit" in the exim configuration. Create an ad-hoc transport with the needed limit and implement some rules to redirect the user(s) you want to that transport.